# Modify the existing contacts in Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am try to edit phone contacts through my app. I want to edit **"Name , Number, Email "**. I am able to edit **Number and Email**. But when I try to edit Name it is not editing

My code as follows

```
ContentResolver contentResolver  = getActivity().getContentResolver();

String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +  ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";

 String[] emailParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
 String[] nameParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
 String[] numberParams = new String[]{ContactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

 ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<android.content.ContentProviderOperation>();

 if(!email.equals("") &&!name.equals("")&& !number.equals(""))
  {
   ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where,emailParams)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
        .build());

   ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ?", new String[] {ContactId})
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        .build());

     ops.add(android.content.ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withSelection(where,numberParams)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
        .build());

    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contact is successfully edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Can any please tell me why name is not editing

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try This. https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/ContactManager

Answer (score 1):

You selection is incorrect

```
withSelection(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ?", new String[] {ContactId})
```

`Phone._ID` is not contactId - its the `Data._ID`.

You have the nameParams defined correctly but for some reason I see you have not used them.

use below instead

```
.withSelection(where,nameParams )
```

Use the same selection that you used for number and email.

Comment: And don't forget to change CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME with CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME